# Trying to loop through all cells that start with the contents of another cell using ARRAYFORMULA and RegExMatch

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet setup; it's for a product import. I am trying to loop through all rows, when C2:C == "configurable" I want it to join (with a comma) all B2:B cells that start with the contents of B in the current "configurable" row.

For example, the table may look like [this.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_DXkwL2eGockNFzgNNcvz0Tlk7wmhPgNDM4A6azrUac/edit?usp=sharing)

```
Name    |  SKU     |  Type           |  Simple Products
Prod 1  |  001     |  configurable   |  001.01,001.02
Prod 2  |  001.01  |  simple         |
Prod 3  |  001.02  |  simple         |
Prod 4  |  002     |  configurable   |  002.01,002.02,002.03
Prod 5  |  002.01  |  simple         |
Prod 6  |  002.02  |  simple         |
Prod 7  |  002.03  |  simple         |
```

The "Simple Products" column (D2) is where the formula would be located. It will scan each row, if C* = configurable, then it will use the B* value to find all "simple" SKUs that start with the value in B*.

I have it almost working, using the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
    IF( 
        C3:C="configurable", 

        join(
            ",", 
            transpose(
                iferror(
                    filter(
                        B3:B,
                        C3:C="simple",
                        RegExMatch(B3:B, B3)
                    )
                )
            )
        ), 

        "" 
    ) 
)
```

However, the above always uses B3 for the RegExMatch, so every configurable row contains `001.01,001.02` rather than the row it is currently outputting data in.

Comment: Would you try sharing it so anyone can edit your spreadsheet? It would make it much easier to help you. Just press the share button in the top right corner.

Comment: @Dehli Thanks, here's the link to an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_DXkwL2eGockNFzgNNcvz0Tlk7wmhPgNDM4A6azrUac/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @pnuts Not aware of a wiki, link?

Comment: The original had an extra row above it, so used the 3rd row. The spreadsheet is using the correct formula. Thanks for the link, I believe the question is valid now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C="configurable",REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(B2:B,,ROWS(B2:B))&" ","(?:"&B2:B&"\.[0-9]+ )+"))," ",","),))`

Although there's a couple of assumptions made based on your sample data (eg the SKUs are sorted).

The issue with your attempt is that the FILTER function can't iterate down the column.

*Credit to [Isai Alvarado](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/t08pwPBjW7w/_9pmX2Py3owJ) who came up with the QUERY method of building very large strings; larger than the 50k character limit that is normally imposed.*

Comment: Wow, that works a treat. Impressive; during my research most of the solutions I found were written by you - I hope you get paid or credit for this stuff!